# Why does Alf crash in the Tanner's garage?

Tags: aliens, tv, soft-sci-fi, alf

I do remember he is from Melmac, eats a lot and a lot of things. But what is the reason that he crashed?

Comment: .....probably holding on tight and screaming

Comment: "One day ALF followed an amateur radio signal to Earth and crash-landed his ship into the garage of the Tanner family. " - http://alf.wikia.com/wiki/ALF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr Tanner was [in his garage scanning various frequencies](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2m054d) when he happened upon a signal from ALF's ship. Mr Tanner tried to make contact with them (assuming the signal was non-local) and the ship then homed in on his radio broadcast, landing a few feet away.

> **Mr Tanner:** *What's that noise? Oh, my gosh! It's the infrared radio band. I've locked in to something in space; a pulsar or a
>   satellite.*   [To mike] Hello? Hello? This is K-7-2-6-X-A-A.
>   *Can you read me? **They're answering, but I don't recognize the language**.*
>
> **Mrs Tanner:** *Why don't you just shut it off? I can't.*
>
> **Mr Tanner:** *I can't control it. It's locked in the signal.*

As to why it *crashed* (as opposed to landing safely), it would appear that the ship was ineptly driven and may well have been slightly broken to begin with, presumably caused during the destruction of <s>Krypton</s> Melmac. Fixing it became an integral part of the ongoing plotline.

Comment: ineptly driven  ...ha nice and refined way to say. I didn't remembered the Melmac event. That makes sense. Thanks